# Can´t add features to an ArcMap project because a GDB lock of my own computer ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, file-geodatabase, lock

I'm trying to add some data from a GDB to an ArcMap project, but i am not abble to do it because of an existing lock.

I have checked the origin of the lock and it says it´s from my own PC. Actually, when I close the project I am able to access the GDB, the problem is that I am making cartography maps, so I need to add the data to that specific project.

I have dealt with locks due to other users accessing the GBD, but never with a lock of my own PC, I dont have idea of how to solve this problem.

PD: The specific project already has some layers from that GDB, the lock problem appeared right after I set the source of the data to that GDB.

Comment: Just to clarify -- You are not in an _Edit Session_ with ArcMap? An open edit session keeps you from being able to modify the gbd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other answers here will usually solve a problem with a lock coming from your own system.  If none of these steps work, such as closing/reopening ArcMap, restarting your machine, etc., you can copy the File GDB in Windows Explorer to another location.  You will be copying the folder with suffix ".gdb".

Going into the copied folder in Windows Explorer, you should be able to manually delete the .lock file(s).  Then, you should be able to add data from the copied GDB from within ArcMap.

Comment: Thanks, it's not optimal but solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

A lock commonly means that another application is accessing a database, and the ability to alter its structure, such as by adding or removing fields, is restricted. A common cause for a schema lock is displaying a dataset while trying to modify the dataset in another application.

Solution - If using multiple applications, check whether those applications might be accessing the same data.

I usually get locks when: 
- someone else is using the data 
- I have multiple programs looking at the data 
- the data is in my mxd multiple times 
- the data is being used in a service and the service hasn't been shut down

Look at your database connections to identify where the multiple connections are coming from, and either disconnect them from there, or manually shut things down.  Does it show you are connected multiple times?  Do you have Catalog and ArcMap both looking at the data?

Answer (score 0):

Try closing and re-opening Arc.  That can often clear a phantom lock.  Failing that, try rebooting.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i have tried that multiple times with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a lock on it? Meaning is the feature class on the table of contents stopping you from adding it to the project? If there a lingering lock on your machine from another use? Can you remove any of the .lock files from the gdb via a file explorer.

I'm trying to follow what the problem is, but it's not easy to understand what is occurring. If you have more than one workspace one then it will cause a lock. Do you have the folder structure open in ArcCatalog?

You state that if you close out then you can access the gdb. But how are you accessing it? Can you give more information?